# Query a has many model, after querying the belongs to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models User and Product and a user `has_many :products`.
Given a set of users, how do i find the products created by them.

**Question**: Find all the products that are available for sale and being sold near a particular address. So I am first finding all the users that live near by. Then querying for all products being sold by those users. Then checking availability on those products. But it does not work. Why so?

In my controller index action I have:

```
@users = User.near(params[:nearby], 20)
@users.find_each do |user|
  @products << user.products_selling # <-- Does not work
end
@products = @products.available
```

`product.rb` model

```
belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id, dependent: :delete
scope :available, -> { where(availableforsale: true) }
```

`user.rb` model

```
has_many :products_selling,  class_name: 'Product'
```

Error is

```
undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
```

Please note-  If I change `<<` to `=` then it works but only the products of the last User is queried on not all the Users (obviously).

Please help

Comment: What is the error and models? This piece of code to small to understand the problem.

Comment: Adding more info to the question

Comment: define `@products` above the loop

Comment: @zishe, Question has been updated.

Comment: @GB, I now get `undefined method `available' for #<Array:0x0000010d5e27f8>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@users = User.near(params[:nearby], 20)

@products = Product.where(["user_id IN (?)", @users.map(&:id)]).available
```

Fixing your code below, (But not a good idea to query inside a loop)

```
@products = [] # initialize empty array before you insert into it
@users.each do |user|
  @products << user.products_selling.to_a # To insert array of products rather than a Relation
  # Now @products is an Array of Arrays.
end
@products = @products.flatten.select(&:availableforsale) # Flatten the Array, and select only the ones availableForSale
```

Comment: @Amey, I have added the fix for your code(should work, hopefully). But  it has an `N+1` issue. ie if the count of `@users` is 100, the total num of queris will be 101. My first solution will only make 2 queries, whatever the count of `@users`

Comment: Yeah, your first solution looks cleaner too. It was the obvious choice. Thanks Again. :)